# Copy specific files within known time range using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, timestamp, copy

I'm recording two time/timestamps using:

```
set "startplay_time=%time%"
```

and

```
set "endplay_time=%time%"
```

and I want to copy files from one directory to another that are created within this `(startplay_time - endplay_time)` time range.

my copy command is as below:

```
for /R "C:\test\BFI\%DSBuild%" %%f in (*.fap *.fps) do copy %%f Server\
```

As you can see above command copies all the files but I would like to copy only those that fall under above time range. I'm interested in copying these `.fap` and `.fps files` **only**.

Is there a way to achieve this using windows batch? For example, I've attempted to get the latest files from folder using:

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "C:\test\DB\*.fps" /B /O:D /S') DO SET NewFile=%%I
copy "%NewFile%" "D:\Latest"
```

but this does not provide any help with time range. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Why didn't you just create one line using `In (*.fap *.fps) Do`?

Comment: you are right, i should do that

Comment: You should also enclose your path with doublequotes `"C:\test\BFI\%DSBuild%"` and your set statements similarly, `Set "startplay_time=%time%"` and `Set "endplay_time=%time%"`. Also providing code which does not attempt to perform the required task and asking for help to make it do so is a code request and off topic. Please attempt the task yourself, and [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51783156/edit) with the attempted code once you have done so.

Comment: Don't try to do date/time arithmetics in batch scripting, do that in a language that natively support it; you could even embed such in your batch file then...

Comment: the question has been updated as per comments

Comment: Getting 'the latest files from folder' has got nothing whatsoever to do with the task has it? You need to attempt the task, i.e. identify the `.fap` and `.fps` files within a tree whose timestamps fall within a specific range! _(I would utilise PowerShell for such a task)_.